# Reformulation of Hamilton's rule

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, evolutionary-game-theory

**Who (and in which article) was the first to reformulate Hamilton's rule using the letters $B$ and $C$?**. See below comments on this reformulation.

Hamilton, in his [1964's article](http://www.uvm.edu/~pdodds/files/papers/others/1964/hamilton1964a.pdf) gave a mathematical formulation to explain the direction of social traits. Below is its formulation. Note: Hamilton used quite a complicated formulation, I hope I am not misunderstanding its meaning. Please let me know if it is the case.

$$R\cdot\frac{dw(x,y,z)}{dx}>\frac{dw(x,y,z)}{dy}$$ where $R$ is the coefficient of relatedness which can itself be expressed as a correlation between the variables $x$ and $y$. $w(x,y,z)$ is the fitness function of a focal individual expressing trait $x$ and interacting with an individual draw from a subpopulation expressing trait $y$ (expected value of the probability distribution of trait expression of individuals in the subpopulation) in a population expressing trait $z$ (expected value again).

Most often this formula is expressed in the following form:

$$RB>C$$

$B$ and $C$ are called cost and benefit of the social trait. I believe that $B$ and $C$ are often not understood as a consequence of a change of the social trait but rather as a cost and benefit of carrying the social trait (compare to not carrying it).

Comment: Interesting question but since B and C basically strip the idea of a lot of mathematical content, isn't it possible that the first use was, say, in a graduate text for non-mathematicians to give a sort of quick idea? That would be hard to track down I bet.

Comment: @daniel Yes that's possible indeed! One thing that got me interested into this question is that $B$ and $C$ are usually conceptually understood a bit differently than $\frac{dw(x,y,z)}{dx}$ and $\frac{dw(x,y,z)}{dy}$ and I am wondering how the first guy has somehow argued for this new understanding of Hamilton's rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracing it backwards this was the earliest reference I found via google scholar, it's [from 1988 and uses the $r B C$ notation](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2461940?seq=7) in the format we are used to.

> Hamilton's rule states that for a social
>   action to be favored under natural selection, rb - c > 0, where c is the cost to the
>   actor in terms of the effect on (usually a reduction in) his expected number of
>   future offspring, bis the benefit to the recipient in terms of the effect on (usually
>   an increase in) his expected number of future offspring, and r is the relatedness of
>   the actor to the recipient

However, I've traced back a bit further by going through the references and found [this Michod paper from 1978](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2097061?seq=2) where they defined terms $b_i$ and $c_i$ as the

> "fitness effect of genotype $i$'s behaviour on others"

and,

> "fitness effect of genotype $i$'s behaviour on self"

respectively, which was the first such notation I could find which could be interpreted as $b$ = benefit via the increased fitness of others and $c$ as a cost to self.

**As far as I can tell** this leaves a 14 year gap between Hamilton's long version and the beginnings of the current notation by Michod in 1978, with the first "rB - c > 0" type of notation appearing in 1988. Obviously my search is not exhaustive - many papers from this period will be hard to find and text search (e.g. using "rB" as a search term) - but it's a good start. If I find an older reference any time I will update.

Comment: (I will try to examine the papers further to try to find both "r = relatedness, b = benefit to recipient, c = cost to provider" and "altruism will evolve if rB>C" types of statements, but that will have to wait - It's quite laborious, even this much took over an hour, and I have a long list of jobs to do by Friday!)

Comment: Nice work. Thanks a lot Robert! Michod in his abstract talk about kin selection theory as the cost-benefit rule as if it was obvious to other people that kin selection theory is a cost-benefit rule. I should check Hamilton's paper to see if he himself used the word cost and benefit.